# Class 'Plugins_AccessCheck' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have created a plugin in zend framework and registered this plugin in bootstrap.php. but my page is showing the error

Class 'Application_Plugin_AccessCheck' not found in bootstrap.php file.

This is my plugin file present in application/plugins/AccessCheck.php

```
 <?php
 class Plugins_AccessCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract{

       public function preDispatch(){

               echo "predispatched function called";
       }
}
```

this is my bootsrap file

```
   <?php


 class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
 {

    protected function _initAutoload()
    {
      $modelLoader = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
        "namespace" => "Application",
        "basePath" => APPLICATION_PATH
    ));


    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new Plugins_AccessCheck());
    $front->dispatch();
    return $modelLoader;
}
}
```

This is my application

```
    [production]
    phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
    phpSettings.display_errors = 1
    includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
    bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
    bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
    appnamespace = "Application"
   resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH"/controllers"                 
    resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
    resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

    resources.db.params.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
    resources.db.params.host ="localhost"
    resources.db.params.username = "root"
    resources.db.params.password = "root"
    resources.db.params.dbname = "zfproject"
    resources.db.params.default = true
```

iam new to zend.idont know wher is my problem .can somebody help

Answer (score 0):

You setup the module autoloader with the namespace `Application`, so try renaming the class to `Application_Plugins_AccessCheck`:

```
class Application_Plugins_AccessCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        echo "predispatched function called";
    }
}
```

and then:

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new Application_Plugins_AccessCheck());
$front->dispatch();
return $modelLoader;
```

Answer (score 0):

changing  class name to Application_Plugin_AccessCheck resolved the issue